# Ошибка при билде Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, monodevelop

[image: при попытке собрать билд получаю этот набор ошибок. Библиотека RacursCore - самописная, в режиме редактора все работает отлично, а при билде вот... В чем проблема?]

при попытке собрать билд получаю этот набор ошибок. Библиотека RacursCore - самописная, в режиме редактора все работает отлично, а при билде вот... В чем проблема?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Unity имеет старый .NET под капотом (если не ошибаюсь, там `.NET Standard 2.1` с версией C#8, что +- тоже самое, что .NET Framework 4.8), который не поддерживает все современные фишки. Вы написали свою библиотеку, которая использует `System.Text.JSON`, которая появилась только с `.NET Core 3`, следовательно, данной библиотеки (на которую ссылается ваша библиотека) в Unity нет. В старые версии .NET Framework она ставиться [отдельным пакетом](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json/#dependencies-body-tab), как в Unity я не знаю, ищите аналоги.

Comment: спасибо, дали правильное направление мыслям.

Answer (score 0):

В итоге помогло добавление актуальных библиотек в /Assets/Plugins/, а именно System.text.json, system.encodings.web, system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe, microsoft.bsl.asyncinterfaces. Версии библиотек актуальные для самописной (например json 7.0.3) и собранные под .netStandard2.0.